# How to get the URL from a file using a shell script

Tags: bash, scripts

I have a file which consists of a [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator). I'm trying to get the URL from that file using a shell script.

In the file, the URL is like this:

```
('URL', 'http://url.com');
```

I tried to use the following:

```
cat file.php | grep 'URL' | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

It gives the output as:

```
'http://url.com');
```

But I need to get only `url.com` in a variable inside the shell script. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like this?

```
grep 'URL' file.php | rev | cut -d "'" -f 2 | rev
```

or

```
grep 'URL' file.php | cut -d "'" -f 4 | sed s/'http:\/\/'/''/g
```

To strip out http://.

Comment: Or: `cat file.php | grep 'URL' | cut -d "'" -f 4`.

Comment: I tried the answer by Frantique it gave `http://url.com` not `url.com`

Comment: @EricCarvalho: Same output in your command as well `http://url.com` not `url.com`

Comment: @Tarun Yes, I just wanted to say that there's no need to double reverse the text.

Comment: See revised answer.

Comment: When you want to match something with `/` in sed, you should usually use a different delimiter, e.g. `sed s@http://@@g`.

Comment: @Frantique: Great answer worked for me thanks a ton :)

Comment: Kevin, not true, you can escape the / as I did it.

Comment: This is very inefficient, though, solution 1 calls 5 processes over 4 pipes, and solution 2 calls 3 processes over 2 pipes including 2 regexes.  This can all be done in the Bash shell without any pipes, processes or dependencies.

Answer (score 14):

You can do everything with a simple `grep`:

```
grep -oP "http://\K[^']+" file.php
```

From `man grep`:

```
   -P, --perl-regexp
          Interpret  PATTERN  as  a  Perl  regular  expression  (PCRE, see
          below).  This is highly experimental and grep  -P  may  warn  of
          unimplemented features.
   -o, --only-matching
          Print  only  the  matched  (non-empty) parts of a matching line,
          with each such part on a separate output line.
```

The trick is to use `\K` which, in Perl regex, means `discard everything matched to the left of the \K`. So, the regular expression looks for strings starting with `http://` (which is then discarded because of the `\K`) followed by as many non-`'` characters as possible. Combined with `-o`, this means that only the URL will be printed.

You could also do it in Perl directly:

```
perl -ne "print if s/.*http:\/\/(.+)\'.*/\$1/" file.php\
```

Comment: very nice answer. +1 from me.

Comment: Very nice compact solution. My favourite too.

Answer (score 5):

Try this,

```bsh
awk -F// '{print $2}' file.php | cut -d "'" -f 1
```

Comment: No didn't worked.

Comment: what is the problem? can you tell me if you are getting it correct `echo "define('URL', 'http://url.com');" | awk -F// '{print $2}' | cut -d "'" -f 1`

Comment: The problem is that the `url.com` to a different url as well like abc.com its dynamic and I need to grab this url using shell script.

Answer (score 4):

Revisiting this again, and trying to use nothing but a Bash shell, another one line solution is:

```
while read url; do url="${url##*/}" && echo "${url%%\'*}"; done < file.in > file.out
```

Where file.in contains the 'dirty' url list and file.out will contain the 'clean' URL list. There are no external dependencies and there is no need to spawn any new processes or subshells.  The original explanation and a more flexible script follows.  There is a good summary of the method [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html), see example 10-10.  This is pattern based parameter substitution in Bash.

Expanding on the idea:

```
src="define('URL', 'http://url.com');"
src="${src##*/}"        # remove the longest string before and including /
echo "${src%%\'*}"      # remove the longest string after and including '
```

Result:

```
url.com
```

No need to call any external programs.  Furthermore, the following bash script, `get_urls.sh`, permits you to read a file directly or from stdin:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# usage: 
#     ./get_urls.sh 'file.in'
#     grep 'URL' 'file.in' | ./get_urls.sh

# assumptions: 
#     there is not more than one url per line of text.
#     the url of interest is a simple one.

# begin get_urls.sh

# get_url 'string'
function get_url(){
  local src="$1"
  src="${src##*/}"        # remove the longest string before and including /
  echo "${src%%\'*}"      # remove the longest string after and including '
}

# read each line.
while read line
do
  echo "$(get_url "$line")"
done < "${1:-/proc/${$}/fd/0}"

# end get_urls.sh
```

Comment: Nice, +1. Strictly speaking though, there is a subshell, the while loop happens in a subshell. On the bright side, this works with just about any shell except `[t]csh`, so it's good for sh, bash, dash, ksh, zsh...

Comment: Bash for the win!

Answer (score 3):

If all the lines contain a URL:

```
awk -F"'|http://" '{print $5}' file.php
```

If only some lines contain a URL:

```
awk -F"'|http://" '/^define/ {print $5}' file.php
```

Depending on the other lines you may need to change the `^define` regex

Comment: It worked just had to add a cut statement the command I used is `awk -F"'|http://" '/^define/ {print $5}' file.php | cut -d ")" -f 1`

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
php -r 'include("file.php"); echo URL;'
```

and if you need to remove the 'http://', then:

```
php -r 'include("file.php"); echo URL;' | sed 's!^http://\(.*\)!\1!'
```

So:

```
myURL=$(php -r 'include("file.php"); echo URL;' | sed 's!^http://\(.*\)!\1!')
```

If you need a certain *part* of the URL you need to refine your terminology, a URL is *all* of the following, sometimes more:

```
URL := protocol://FQDN[/path][?arguments]

FQDN := [hostname.]domain.tld
```

Answer (score 0):

for me, the other `grep` answers given return string information after the link.

This worked for me to only pull out the `url`:

```
egrep -o "(http(s)?://){1}[^'\"]+"
```